# Open NetApp CIFS Share

Tags: authentication, cifs, netapp

I have a CIFS share on a NetApp device.  I want this share to be completely open to any user/computer on the same network.  I don't want any authentication (domain, workgroup, etc) required; no login/password should need to be provided.

Currently I have CIFS configured to use "Domain - Windows 2000" authentication and have the permissions on the share set to "Everyone - Full Read/Write" but if you try to connect to it from a machine that isn't bound to the domain it is asking for login info.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the domain trust level of authentication.  If you're going from a non-domain client to a domain server, it'll always ask for a username/password.  As far as I know, this cannot be circumvented.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about NetApp specifically, but you may need to explicitly allow ANONYMOUS LOGIN, Guest, or Guests on the share. You may also need to do the same thing for the NTFS permissions for the actual files and folders, if NetApp does things the same way as Windows. Since it's CIFS, I'm assuming it does.

Answer (score 0):

For 7-mode, you need to configure the guest account.  Unauthenticated CIFS users are mapped to this account.  It is set with `options cifs.guest_account`.  From the man page:

> ```
>    cifs.guest_account
>        Enables a user to get access  to  the  filer  provided
>        that  either  the  filer  uses a Domain Controller for
>        authentication and  the  user  is  not  in  a  trusted
>        domain,  or the filer uses the /etc/passwd file or the
>        NIS password database for authentication and the  user
>        has  no entry in the /etc/passwd file or the NIS pass-
>        word database.  If this option is set to the  name  of
>        an  account  in  the password database, a user logging
>        into the filer will be assigned to the  guest  account
>        if  their  name is not listed in the password database
>        (when using /etc/passwd or NIS) or if the user is  not
>        from  a  trusted  domain  (when  using  a  domain con-
>        troller). The configured user name will  be  used  for
>        the UNIX user ID, group ID, and group set of the spec-
>        ified account. If the option  is  set  to  ""  (null),
>        guest access is disabled.
>
>        Default: "" (null)
> ```